# How to delete a specific item from a complex data structure while preserving the state in React-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

My current state structure looks something like this:

> //state { datasets:[   {
>       sessions:[]   },   {},   {} ] }

Initially the datasets are displayed on a table. Once you select a specific dataset it shows you all the sessions in that dataset in a table format. 
I am trying to delete one session from that and returning the whole modified state.

I have tried using the slice methods by trying

> return[
>   ...state.datasets[IndexofDataset].sessions.slice(0,action.index),
>   ...state.datasets[IndexofDataset].sessions.slice(action.index +1) ];

NOTE: IndexofDataset represents which dataset was clicked and index represents which session was clicked to be deleted.  I know this will just return an array so i tried making a copy of the state and overwriting just the original sessions array with this newly created array. It makes more sense in the code im posting below.

````
```javascript
    function getDataset(state = {}, action) {
      return [...state.slice(0, action.index), ...state.slice(action.index + 1)];
    }

    function getSessions(state = {}, action) {
      console.log(state);
      return [
        ...state.datasets[action.studyID].sessions.slice(0, action.index),
        ...state.datasets[action.studyID].sessions.slice(action.index + 1)
      ];
    }

    export default function metadata(state = {}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "DELETE_DATASET":
          return {
            //take the current state
            ...state,
            // overwrite this dataset with a new one
            datasets: getDataset(state.datasets, action)
          };

        case "DELETE_SESSION":
          return {
            ...state,
            datasets: getSessions(state, action)
          };

        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
    ```
````

This is the reducer. The DELETE_DATASET case works just fine but i cannot seem to replicate that functionality

````
```javascript
export function deleteSession(studyID, index) {
  return {
    type: "DELETE_SESSION",
    studyID,
    index
  };
}
```
````

This is the action that is fired when the delete button is pressed on the session table.

````
```javascript
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SessionTable from "../backend/SessionTable";

import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actionCreators from "../../../actions/actionCreators";

class Sessions extends Component {
  handleDelete = (studyID, index) => {
    this.props.deleteSession(studyID, index);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Sessions</h1>
        <SessionTable
          data={this.props.metadata}
          index={this.props.match.params.studyID}
          onDelete={this.handleDelete}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    metadata: state.metadata
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Sessions);
```
````

This is the component that renders the sessionTable, once you click the delete button on a sessionTable row it raises an onDelete event to this component which then calls the deleteSession action function.

````
```javascript
class SessionTable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {/* display row with all table column titles */}
              {header.map((h, i) => (
                <th key={i} i={i}>
                  {" "}
                  {h}{" "}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {/* display all sessions with in the specified study*/}
            {this.props.data.datasets[this.props.index].sessions.map(
              (data, i) => (
                <tr key={i} i={i}>
                  <td i={i}>
                    <Link to={this.url(i, this.props.index)}>{data.name}</Link>
                  </td>
                  <td>{data.start_time}</td>
                  <td>{data.end_time}</td>
                  <td>{data.date_created}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.props.onDelete(this.props.index, i);
                      }}
                      className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default SessionTable;
```
````

SessionTable.js

The DELETE_DATASET returns the state with the datasets array overwritten by a new array that has the corresponding dataset deleted. I want to replicate this functionality with the DELETE_SESSION case but it doesnt seem to work.

The error i get in sessionTable is TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. This is because the current implementation deletes all sessions and sessionTable is trying to map an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach. May not be the most efficient, but it works

```
 function getSessions(state = [], action) {
      console.log(state);
      return [
        ...state.map((el, idx) => {
            if (action.studyID === idx){
                    return {
                    ...el,
                    sessions:[...el.sessions.slice(0, action.id), ...el.sessions.slice(action.id + 1)]
                }
            }
            return el;   
        })
      ];
    }

function metadata(state = {}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "DELETE_DATASET":
          return {
            //take the current state
            ...state,
            // overwrite this dataset with a new one
            datasets: getDataset(state.datasets, action)
          };

        case "DELETE_SESSION":
          return {
            ...state,
            datasets: getSessions(state.datasets, action)
          };

        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Comment: action.studyID is type string so triple equals doesnt work. I converted it to int and worked fine.The solution worked for me.Thank you so much.